# Post upgrade gcc compilation fails - cannot find shared file object (libmpc.so.2)

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-14.04

Post upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 -> 14.04, gcc compilation fails.

Compiler and flags used:

> gcc -c -MMD -MP main.c -o main.o -std=gnu99 -lpthread -fstrict-overflow -Werror -Wall -Wshadow -Wstrict-overflow=5 -pedantic -O2 -lm -lpthread -lrt

The error returned is:

> /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.3/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've looked into this location and `libmpc.so.2` is nowhere to be found.

I have tried to look for this package and I've checked all the posts I can on stackoverflow and other forums, but to no real applicable solution.

I have tried to reinstall *gcc* and *libmpc-dev* and they complete with no problems. If I try to reinstall `libmpc3` it doesn't explicitly fail, but the final message returned is:

> /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

I read that the problem could be with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environmental variable (echo returned nothing), so I set it in */etc/ld.so.conf* which contained the following line:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

I added the path `/usr/local/lib` to the bottom of the conf file, but I suppose that's useless because I can't even find `libmpc.so.2` let alone point gcc to the right location. However, after attempting to update the dynamic loader cache by running `ldconfig`, the following line is returned:

> /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

And so, a few questions:

1. Preupgrade everything was working just fine. What did the upgrade
   break?
2. How do I obtain the file *libmpc.so.2*? Which package do you need to get and how do i find out where was the installation location?
3. What's this about magic bytes and what should I do about it? Resources online have suggested this to be a bug?

Thank you taking the time to read this, I'm a linux newbie so I appreciate all the help I can get.

Edit: Foolishly I forgot to add the version of gcc. *gcc --version* returns

> gcc (GCC) 4.8.3

Comment: It seems installation issue. Try launching `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib";  sudo ldconfig`

Comment: Tried but sadly no change. the ldconfig command returns the magic bytes message.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted in  askubuntu!

Comment: _"I have tried to reinstall gcc and libmpc-dev and they complete with no problems."_ How are you installing them? In Ubuntu 14.04 [the gcc package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/devel/gcc-4.8) depends on [libmpc3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libmpc3) which uses [libmpc.so.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libmpc3/filelist) not libmpc.so.2 so I think you've messed up the upgrade somehow.

Comment: Also, you do not want the -dev package for the shared library, you want the main package. So `libmpc3` is the right package to install, assuming you want libmpc.so.3

Comment: I install using `apt-get`. I installed _libmpc3_, but it was already installed. _--reinstall_  completed successfully.

Comment: See my answer, the problem is that you're not using the _gcc_ package, you're using some hand-built version in /usr/local that is not compatible with your new system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the GCC file is `/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.3/cc1` which shows it is in `/usr/local` and system packages are never installed in `/usr/local`

That means someone had installed GCC 4.8.3 by hand in the old Ubuntu 12.04 system. You cannot use that GCC now that you've updated your system, because it was built for a different version of the OS. It was linked against `libmpc.so.2` but that file is not present in Ubuntu 14.04 and cannot be installed using apt.

Install GCC from the Ubuntu repositories and stop using the one in `/usr/local`, the latest GCC for 14.04 is 4.8.4 which is newer anyway:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/gcc-4.8

That will install a working compiler that uses the version of libmpc present in 14.04 (which is [libmpc.so.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libmpc3/filelist))

You should probably delete the whole GCC installation in `/usr/local/`, or at least remove it from your PATH so it isn't used.

Typing `type -a gcc` at a shell prompt will show you all the `gcc` executables in your PATH, which I expect will show:

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

The first one is the broken version that you are using, but is incompatible with your upgraded system. The second one is the one installed by the *gcc* package, and is the one you should be using.

Answer (score 2):

3. The magic bytes stuff can be ignored. https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2014-08/msg00053.html
4. libmpc can be installed using sudo apt-get install libmpc3 [edited after comment]
5. To fully answer this can you please post the version of gcc you are using, and if you manually tried to install a newer version of gcc and did you try to clean the build directory before compiling again?

Comment: My apologies. the version is gcc (GCC) 4.8.3. I included this information in the question as well. Tried to install libmpc-dev, it was already installed, using the _--reinstall_ flag completed with no problems.

Comment: libmpc-dev installs headers and the .so file, not the .so.2 file, that's in the main (not dev) package.